# I downloaded the mp4 file using Lua script, but TikTok(Other apps) cannot find the video

Tags: android, shell, http, lua

After successfully downloading the mp4 file using the Lua script on the Android phone, the system Videos cannot detect the 1.mp4 file, and the video cannot be found in TikTok to publish.

I downloaded 1.mp4 using a script.

I manually copied 1.mp4 to become copy.mp4.

1.mp4 cannot be detected by tiktok

copy.mp4 can be detected by tiktok

Neither file is hidden

I checked the permissions of two files :

```
-rw-rw---- root sdcard_ rw 6939904 2020-11-12 22:07 1. mp4

-rw-rw---- root sdcard_ rw 6939904 2020-11-12 22:15 copy. mp4
```

I don’t know why 1.mp4 is not found

Is there any way to make tiktok(Other apps) recognize 1.mp4

My code:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
severfileTXTpath = "https://ttmakemoney.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/1.mp4"
localfileTXTpath = "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/1.mp4"
local body, code = http.request(severfileTXTpath)
if not body then error(code) end
local f = assert(io.open(localfileTXTpath, 'wb'))
f:write(body)
f:close()
```

You can see the effect through the picture

[image: 1]

---

Setelah salinan yang berjaya gagal, sistem video Android tidak dapat mengesan video copy.mp4,
dan juga tidak dapat mencari video copy.mp4 yang akan diterbitkan di TikTok.

```
 local ts = require("ts")
 path1 = "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/copy.mp4" 
 path2 = "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/1.mp4"
 os.execute("cp " ..path1.. " "..path2)
```

1.mp4 can be detected by tiktok

copy.mp4 cannot be detected by tiktok

I don't know what is wrong?

I checked the permissions of two files (adb):

```
-rw-rw---- root sdcard_rw 6939904 2020-11-13 20:21 1. mp4

-rw-rw---- root sdcard_rw 6939904 2020-11-14 1:54 copy. mp4
```

You can see the effect through the picture

[image]

Comment: Unclear how you are running Lua on Android device. Be aware of the media store which is used by Java/Kotlin Android apps: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Comment: I think this is not caused by network requests.
When I use only one command to copy the code,
The same problem occurred.


I manually copied 1.mp4 to become copy.mp4.



path1 = "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/copy.mp4"

path2 =  "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/2.mp4"

os.execute("cp " ..path1.. "  "..path2)


2.mp4 cannot be detected by tiktok


copy.mp4 can be detected by tiktok



I don't know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think "body" in your script is actually the "OK status" being returned.  Also, you attempting to open an https socket with http.  This should do, just change URL and path.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

--  luarocks install luasocket
--  luarocks install luasec

--  local http = require( 'socket.http' )
local https = require( 'ssl.https' )
local ltn12 = require( 'ltn12' )

local URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doyousketch2/the3dPen/master/icon.png"
local path = "/home/sketch2/Downloads/icon.png"

local oput = io.open( path, 'wb' )
local ok, code, headers, text = https .request { url = URL,  sink = ltn12.sink.file( oput ) }

print( 'ok:',  ok )
print( 'code:',  code,  text )
if headers then
    print( 'headers:' )
    for i, v in pairs( headers ) do
        print( '  ' ..i ..':', v )
    end
end
```

based off of  --  https://gist.github.com/Core-commits/0eaaa00eac5e89e68631fedd72831675

---

luasec is similar to luasocket, but allows https connections.

[http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/http.html)
[http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/ltn12.html](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/ltn12.html)

Comment: local https = require( 'ssl.https' )
local ltn12 = require( 'ltn12' )
Where can I download these two so files?

Comment: I think this is not caused by network requests.
When I use only one command to copy the code,
The same problem occurred.


I manually copied 1.mp4 to become copy.mp4.



path1 = "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/copy.mp4"

path2 =  "/sdcard/Download/aliyunPZ/1/2.mp4"

os.execute("cp " ..path1.. "  "..path2)


2.mp4 cannot be detected by tiktok


copy.mp4 can be detected by tiktok



I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: "Where can I download these two .so files?"  --  I have it commented in there, it's:  `luarocks install luasocket` and `luarocks install luasec`  --  This script works fine over here.  Vid's a teapot, then a guy chopping down bamboo with an axe / hatchet.  I only used this script to download it, nothing else.